# Load and Save Data in Bootstrap popup modal in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using master page for my web application there is a content page we can call it Banks data has a GridView displays all banks and has an Edit,Add,Delete buttons 
I wand display a bootstrap modal with input data to edit or add new bank and to validate using asp RequiredFieldValidator

this is the ASPX Code

```
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="bankCode" HeaderText="Bank Code" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="bankName" HeaderText="Bank Name" />

                                    <asp:TemplateField  >
                                       <ItemTemplate >
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_Edit" runat="server"  CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddBankModal"  CommandName="BankEdit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("bankCode") %>' OnClick="lb_Edit_Click"><strong>Edit</strong></asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LB_Delete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-danger" CommandName="BankDelete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("bankCode") %>'><strong>Delete</strong></asp:LinkButton>

                                       </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                    <RowStyle Height="15px" HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle"  />

                                 </asp:GridView>
                               <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStringDb1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [bankCode], [bankNameAr], [bankNameEng] FROM [Bank]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="AddBankModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content" >
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:right">Bank Data </h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body"> 


                               <asp:Label ID="lblBankCode" runat="server" Text="Bank Code" CssClass="label" style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></asp:Label>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="txtBankCode" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

                               <asp:Label ID="lblBankNameAr" runat="server" Text="Bank Name" CssClass="label" style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold"></asp:Label>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="txtBankNameAr" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>  


                               <div class="row" >
                                   <div class="col-lg-12">

                                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateBank" runat="server" Text="Save Data" CssClass="btn btn-outline btn-primary" style="width:100px" OnClick="btnUpdateBank_Click" />
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" style="width:100px">Close</button>
                                   </div>
                               </div>



                            </div>

                                </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
```

Does any one have any Ideas to do this using ASP code behind without using Jquery

Answer (score 0):

May be you need some thing like this.Remember two things

1.Dont forget to  add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to asp.net control

2.Postback is prevented by  `e.preventDefault()` to add jQuery functionality in click event

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField  >
                                       <ItemTemplate >
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_Edit" runat="server"  CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddBankModal" ClientIDMode="Static"><strong>Edit</strong>
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                       </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <div id="AddBankModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        &times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: right">
                        Bank Data
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblBankCode" runat="server" Text="Bank Code" CssClass="label" Style="text-align: right;
                        font-weight: bold"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBankCode" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblBankNameAr" runat="server" Text="Bank Name" CssClass="label" Style="text-align: right;
                        font-weight: bold"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBankNameAr" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateBank" runat="server" Text="Save Data" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="btn btn-outline btn-primary"
                                Style="width: 100px"  />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" style="width: 100px">
                                Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var buttonid = $(this).attr('id');
                console.log(buttonid);
                if (buttonid == "lb_Edit") {
                    $('#AddBankModal').modal({
                        show: true,
                        backdrop: 'static'
                    });
                }
                if (buttonid == "btnUpdateBank") {
                    //
                    alert('Do some ajax to send data to Backend');
                }
                //currentRow.remove();

            });
        })
    </script>
```